# Sincronizar atributos componente angular

Tags: angularjs, jade, bower

Estoy utilizando un componente bower "externo" (aunque si es necesario lo puedo modificar) para la subida de ficheros a un servidor. Este componente cuando finaliza la subida notifica a un método de mi controlador y establece en el modelo un identificador de subida. La cuestión es que desde mi controlador cuando tengo más de un elemento no funciona.

El componente al enviar hace:

```
function ctoUpload() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            identificador: '=',
            identificadorObj: '=',
            onSuccess: '&'
        },
        controller: UploadFilesController,
        controllerAs: 'uploadController',
        templateUrl: '{{lang}}/upload.html',
        bindToController: true
    };
}


  function uploadFile() {
        var inputArchivo =document.getElementById('file' + uploadController.identificadorObj);
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', inputArchivo.files[0]);
         var onsuccess = uploadController.onSuccess;

        uploadService.subirFichero(formData,  onsuccess).success(function (response, status) {
            if (_.isFunction(onsuccess)) {
                uploadController.identificador = response.id;//id correcto
                            result = $q.when(uploadController.onSuccess.apply(this));
```

result.then(function () {...

Mi "callback" hace lo siguiente:

```
vm.upload = function(file) {
     var id = vm.identificador;//aquí id vale erróneamente el anterior
     ...
```

El jade:

```
cto-upload(id="opt"+"vm.identificador",identificador="vm.identificador", 
           on-success="vm.upload(file)"..
```

El resultado es que al subir un fichero vm.identificador vale "" al subir el segundo coge el anterior y así sucesivamente. He probado con $scope.apply y $scope.$evalAsync sin éxito. Depurando veo que al componente llegan todos los datos correctamente pero no se actualiza en mi modelo. ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba realizar la logica que interactúa con componentes angular dentro de una función manejada por el ciclo de vida de angular, como `$timeout`

```
uploadService.subirFichero(formData,  onsuccess).success(function (response, status) {
    if (_.isFunction(onsuccess)) {
        $timeout(function (){
            /* tu logica aqui*/
        });
    }
});
```

Esto porque la asignación que haces:

```
uploadController.identificador = ...
```

No es visible en un ciclo de [digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)